# Turning a book into a video of the book with its pages turning one by one

Tags: software-recommendation, book, video

I have a 60-page (i.e., 30-sheet) book (to be more specific, a photobook). I'd like to create a video showing the book with its pages turning one by one (e.g., ~10 sec per sheet or so, then turning to the next sheet). How can I create such a video?

One [could](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/158999/11980) serve the book as an interactive webpage where readers can flip pages, with some page flipping effect, and then record a video, but I'd prefer a more automated solution (input: images + some parameters/options; output: video).

Comment: http://www.video.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Scott thanks, indeed I wasn't sure. Happy to migrate!