# Serving a book as an interactive webpage where readers can flip pages, with some page flipping effect

Tags: website-design, software-recommendation, book, interactive

I have a 60-page (i.e., 30-sheet) book (to be more specific, a photobook), in JPG format.
I'd like to serve the book as an interactive webpage where readers can flip pages, with some page flipping effect. How can I create such an interactive book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the JS Library [StPageFlip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/page-flip) (MIT license).

[Example](https://github.com/Nodlik/StPageFlip/blob/HEAD/video.gif) from this [online demo](https://nodlik.github.io/StPageFlip/demo.html):

[image]

Images are loaded via `loadFromImages()`:

```
pageFlip.loadFromImages(['path/to/image1.jpg', 'path/to/image2.jpg' ... ]);
```